# Does Itext 5.5.13.3 support Transparent pdf backgrounds?

Tags: java, pdf, netbeans, itext, opacity

I am working on an existing codebase which is using Itext 5.5.13.3, I found this page https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it5kb/faq/how-to-change-a-background-image-into-a-watermark-by-altering-the-opacity which seems to be about image transparency and the background transparency link is dead.

I have not attempted anything and I am simply wondering if it is possible with this version of Itext and where I can look for the proper documentation or method. I am using Netbeans and writing in Java

Edit: I want to have an option that allows the user to export a PDF with transparent/no background from my program similar to how it is done in PNG. The buttons are already functional, all I am missing is the actual pdf logic

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want transparency information already in the image to be used by iText? Or do you want to make add transparency to opaque images when adding them to a PDF?

Comment: I added an edit to clarify, but I want to basically only export my image as a pdf and not the background, either by making it completely transparent or removing it altogether

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct link to the background transparency example - https://github.com/itext/i5js-sandbox/blob/master/src/main/java/sandbox/images/BackgroundTransparent.java

If you (or anyone else) want the equivalent example for iText 7, you can find it here - https://github.com/itext/i7js-examples/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/images/BackgroundTransparent.java, or here for the C# version - https://github.com/itext/i7ns-samples/blob/develop/itext/itext.samples/itext/samples/sandbox/images/BackgroundTransparent.cs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).